# How to implement an IN clause in LinQ

Tags: linq, generics, c#-3.0

I have two ILIst of these objects:

```
    class ProductionMachineType
    {
        string code { get; set; }
        IEnumerable<string> ProductionToolsLink { get; set; }
    }

    class ProductionTools
    {
        string code { get; set; }
    }
```

I am looking for a fast Linq method that make me able to query the `IList<ProductionMachineType>` that contains at least one `ProductionToolsLink` contained inside the `ILIst<ProductionTools>`.

In SQL I would wite something like this:

```
SELECT 
      * 
FROM 
      IList<ProductionMachineType>
WHERE 
      IList<ProductionMachineType>.ProductionToolsLink IN ILIst<ProductionTools>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it, but I can't guarantee how efficient it is...

```
var output = machines.Where(machine => 
     machine.ProductionToolsLink
     .Any(link => tools.Select(tool => tool.code).Contains(link)));
```

Comment: Ok this is the righr answer. The efficienty probles is know but I cannoto any different approach cause of our bad Domain Model.

The query linq is also pretty much complicated. So I think I will use a couple of foreach to improve clarity.

Answer (score 5):

*Contains* method can help you:

```
var names = new string[] { "Alex", "Colin", "Danny", "Diego" };

var matches = from person in people
        where names.Contains(person.Firstname)
        select person;
```

Comment: Does not work if "names" is another Entity, it outputs an "EXISTS", not an "IN"